# Php Classes Unique Data Member

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm really new in PHP, our instructor just teaching us C++ OOP and I want to try it on PHP.

I'm creating objects with my class.

```
class TwitterUser {

    private $twittername;
    public function TwitterUser($a)
    {
        $this->twittername = $a;
        // echo $this->twittername;


    }

}



  $reader = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($target_path);

$veriler = $reader->sheets[0]['cells'];
foreach($veriler as $veri)
{
if(!empty($veri[$sutun]) and $veri[$sutun]!="Twitter")
    {
    $kisiler[] = new TwitterUser(temizle($veri[$sutun]));

    }
}
```

What I want is, if one object has same string with other object in `$twittername` data member, don't create new object.

Comment: Just a note, in PHP, the constructor function should be named `__construct()`, and not "ClassName".

Comment: @MadaraUchiha i tried both and they worked same. what is the differance ?

Comment: @1342: If you need to change your class name, or have an extending constructor, you won't need to change the method's name. `public function ClassName` was the old way of defining constructors.

Comment: You don't want the object to be added to the array if the  $twittername is "test" ?

Comment: @Makita if there is already an object has $twittername="test" , yes

Comment: The object you instantiate will not have knowledge of previous objects. Where are you getting the list of twitter names? I assume you are not calling the all "test"?

Comment: @Madara Uchiha There is no such restriction in PHP. The constructor _may_ be named `__constructor` or _may_ have the same name as the class. Both work.

Comment: @Makita i'm fetching them Excel file (xls)

Comment: @MarcellFülöp: It's no longer recommended to use `ClassName`, even though it's accepted.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp i used that way, because we are learning c++ oop in my university right now and that's how my preceptor doing that in c++ :)

Answer (score 0):

This task is usually done using some kind of Model -> database approach (such as Doctrine), in which case you save the model data into database. The database table should be designed to not allow the same name for more than one record and the logic to enforce and error handle this can be built into the model class.

You can achieve the same by pure PHP, but it requires existing instances to be stored somehow so when creating new instances, existing ones can be checked for uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks, actually i have to use database in this project. Now i'll insert datas which comes from excel in a table and create objects later.
If someone knows how to do it with pure PHP, please answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add the object if the username is test? Basically you can't back out of a constructor. Just add a simple flag to only add "test" user once.

Using your code sample:

```
$testuserexists = false;
foreach($veriler as $veri)
{
    if(!empty($veri[$sutun]) and $veri[$sutun]!="Twitter" && $testuser == false)
    {
        $kisiler[] = new TwitterUser(temizle($veri[$sutun]));
        if ($veri[$sutun] == "Test")
            $testuserexists = true;

    }
}
```

Or if you are trying to not have duplicates:

```
foreach($veriler as $veri)
{
    if(!empty($veri[$sutun]) and $veri[$sutun]!="Twitter" && !isset($kisiler[$veri[$sutun]]))
    {
        $kisiler[$veri[$sutun]] = new TwitterUser(temizle($veri[$sutun]));
    }
}
```

I don't know what the temizle function is supposed to do, but basically you can assign the username as the associative array key and prevent duplicates by adding an isset() to your conditional.

Comment: Test was an example. I want to prevent duplicates.